# TEXINPUTS on Windows

Tags: pdftex, texlive, windows, texinputs

I am writing an application which generates .tex filed and invokes pdflatex (on windows/texlive for now, but it should be compatible with toher distros and OS).

I would like to enable the user to include custom directories for resources shared between the generated .tex files.
Under Linux I had done that simply by setting the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.

Now under windows, initially the variable is empty, so I cannot just "append" stuff there.
However, If I set `TEXINPUTS` to any paths, pdflatex seems to exclusively check these paths, and forget about whatever it had checked before.
doesn't reconize the default paths anymore.
This results in pdflatex not even finding the input file anymore 
[image: input file not found]

If the input file is specified manually, then any resources within the tex file are not found anymore, starting with the document class file:
[image: cls file not found]

How do I properly add input paths on windows?

Comment: Are you setting with the 'and default' paths ending (trailing `;`), _e.g._ I have `set TEXINPUTS=.;C:\Users\joseph\Documents\LaTeX\local\\;C:\Users\joseph\Documents\LaTeX\beamer\base\\;`

Comment: Oh wow ... I think that did it. :) - didn't know the trailing ; had that semantic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `TEXINPUTS` isn't set, TeX acts in the same way

```
set TEXINPUTS=.;
```

Notice in particular the trailing `;`. This means 'then follow up with the standard locations'. Thus if we want to *add* a location (say `C:\SharedTeX`), we need to _retain`the trailing`;`

```
set TEXINPUTS=.;C:\SharedTeX;
```

(I've also kept `.`, *i.e.* the current directory, as this is usually sensible.)

The only time you don't want the trailing `;` is if you want to 'isolate' a run from the standard tree: only really useful for low-level testing. (The LaTeX team do exactly that to test during kernel development.)