# How to tell texlive where to look for \input files

Tags: texlive

On a Windows XP machine, I'm trying to switch from MiKTex 2.9 to TeX Live 2011.

I just installed texlive from the iso DVD image to the directory "C:\apps\texlive".

I have a latex file "tst.tex" in a directory "E:\latex\tst".

Contents of tst.tex:

```
   \input defaults
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \begin{document}
   Hello world!
   \end{document}
```

The file "defaults.tex" contains some settings and it resides in the directory "E:\latex\inc".

To build "tst.dvi" I have a batch file "bld.bat" residing in the same directory as "tst.tex" with the following contents:

```
   @echo off
   set path=C:\apps\texlive\bin\win32
   latex.exe -halt-on-error tst.tex >nul
   pause
```

Of course it fails since texlive has no idea where to find "defaults.tex".

In MiKTex, I would use the command line option

```
   --include-directory E:\latex\inc
```

but it appears that texlive has no such command line option.

I need to somehow tell texlive to look for input files in some central common subdirectory of "E:\".

I very much want to avoid hard-coding the full path for "defaults.tex".

I can make whatever subdirectories of "E:\" are needed, and I can edit bld.bat to set any needed environmental variables.

I would prefer not to make any permanent changes to texlive settings or to the contents of any texlive directories.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

As a possible alternative, is it possible to set an environmental variable in my bld.bat file which will tell texlive that my home directory is somewhere on the E: drive, and based on that setting, is there a subdirectory where texlive will automatically search for input files?

Comment: Are you really trying to install a version from 2011??

Comment: For Windows XP, that's the latest, I think. It works fine, my only issue is the problem with customizing the location for input files.

Comment: Well you probably can set texinputs. But imho it isn't the best idea to use an 11 years old tex on an outdated OS. You can't expect much support here, and there have been many changes in the past years.

Comment: For now, I'll have to live with the XP version. Apparently texinputs is an environmental variable, so I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't write how you did set texinputs. Did you replace the backslash by slashed? Beside this you can use the texmf-local or texmfhome tree.

Comment: Or you could use a relative path: \input ../inc/defaults And I believe that 2017 is the latest release which supports xp.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Correcting my earlier comment, if I insert  the command "set TEXINPUTS=E:\_\TeX\_LaTeX\_inc:" in my batch file, latex doesn't complain about " \input defaults" but I get the error message "file article.cls" not found.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410350/texinputs-on-windows

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: That link clinched it! I needed a semicolon to terminate the set texinputs command, not a colon. It works now! Thanks very much for the help (and for your patience).

Comment: @Siep: I would be happy to switch to a 2017 version of texlive if it will install on Windows XP. Can you provide a link to an iso image?

Comment: ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/texlive2017-20170524.iso

Comment: @Siep: Thanks a lot. I'll try it!

Comment: @Siep: Using the link you provided, I now have Tex Live 2017 installed and tested on my XP machine. Thank you very much! .

Comment: At this point, thanks to Ulrike Fischer and Siep, all my issues with Tex Live are resolved. Should I delete my question or leave it as is?